# How can I create DNS A records in CoreDNS manually?

Tags: dns, kubernetes

My question is how can I create DNS A records in CoreDNS manually?

Comment: Posssibility>>>>>https://coredns.io/2017/05/08/custom-dns-entries-for-kubernetes/

Comment: Adding every time values to configmap - it is strage solution IMO